# Python pickle got acycle recursion with getattr?

Tags: python, pickle, getattr

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.a, name)

from pickle import loads, dumps
loads(dumps((Test(something),)))
```

I got:

```
      7     def __getattr__(self, name):
----> 8         return getattr(self.a, name)

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

any hint?

I can fix this by changing the code like:

```
if 'a' in self.__dict__:
    return getattr(self.a, name)
```

but I don't want to. Any better solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `getattr()` instead of `__getattr__`. This would be equivalent to calling `getattr(Test(a).a, name)`. This first turns to `a.__getattribute__` and if that fails then to `a.__getattr__`

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = a

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        a = object.__getattribute__(self, '_a')
        return getattr(a, name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but I doubt it's a good idea...

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        a = object.__getattribute__(self, 'a')
        return a.__getattr__(a, name)

from pickle import loads, dumps
loads(dumps((Test({}))))
# <__main__.Test at 0x7f6beb8>
```